# compiling amqsput0.c [MQ]

Tags: c, ibm-mq, mq

I'm new to MQ. I'm trying to compile amqsget0.c file for testing purpose with slight modification. 
But whenever it try to connect to the Queue, it returns with an error

<02:17:16>Successfully connected to MQ Queue Manager QMGR
<02:17:16>MQ Open to Queue QNME
Failed with reason code 8667514137712 (printing reason code returned from MQCONN.)

for compiling - [in AIX 6.1 machine ]
`cc -g -q64 -qcpluscmt -c amqsget0.c`
`cc -g -q64 -qcpluscmt amqsget0.o -L/usr/mqm/lib64 -lmqm_r -o amqsget`

But my friend was able to compile the same thing and the executable is working properly in my machine.

my machine
    `dspmqver

    Name: WebSphere MQ

    Version: 7.5.0.0`

his machine
`dspmqver

Name: WebSphere MQ

Version: 7.0.0.0`

Can anyone point if I'm missing anything while compiling? or any pointer where I should check? Or I have missed any configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Solved.. was my compilation mistake